# How Slug works for URL rewrite Meteor?

Tags: url, meteor, url-rewriting, package

I read the article about URL rewrite in Meteor, and I found Slug for recommendation to use in url, but I didn't understand how it works. Please Someone Explain me. Thanks.

```
Router.route('/blog/:slug',{
    name:'blogPosts',
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('collection'); },
    data: function(){
        var slug = this.params.slug;
        return Collection.findOne({slug:slug});
        // this is saying search the collection's slug for the passed in parameter which we're also calling "slug"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code uses the `iron:router` package. I recommend reading the documentation for that package here: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router

As to what this code does, when a user goes to a route such as `localhost:3000/blog/first-post`, the route you posted will run. This code subscribes to the publication whose name is `'collection'` (that's the `waitOn` block).

In the `data` block, `this.params.slug` will be equal to `'first-post'`. We then search the collection for a post whose slug is equal to `'first-post'` which we then return as the data context for our template to use.

But you should really read the `iron-router` documentation for a fuller understanding.